# error with first time deploy to google compute engine.

Tags: google-compute-engine, gcloud

Experimenting with google compute engine but unable to deploy a simple sinatra app. I get this error and i'm not sure how to troubleshoot.

```
ERROR: (gcloud.preview.app.deploy) Docker build aborted: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v1/repositories/google/ruby-runtime/tags: EOF
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My mistake. Changed app.yml to app.yaml
Works now.

Comment: What was your command line when you ran before and got the error? Were you running it as `gcloud preview app deploy app.yml` or did you specify `app.yaml` while the file was called `app.yml`? I'd like to see if we can reproduce this failure for a bug report.

Comment: the file was called app.yml. I had to rename to app.yaml and ran gcloud preview app deploy app.yaml.